# Ubuntu Thunderbolt docking station Monitors not working

Tags: multiple-monitors, thunderbolt, kvm-switch

I am trying to get my Ubuntu laptop to work with my new docking station, with passthrough of everything via just thunderbolt.

- Docking Station: [i-tec USB-C/Thunderbolt KVM Docking station Dual Display + Power Delivery 65/100W](https://i-tec.pro/en-us/produkt/c31dualkvmdockpd-10/)

  - Thunderbolt 4 input
  - 1 HDMI, 1 DisplayPort output
- Laptop: [System76 Darter Pro (darp5)](https://system76.com/laptops/darter) ([Specs](https://support.system76.com/service-manuals/pdfs/Darter/darp5-service-manual.pdf))

  - Uses Integrated Intel Graphics (`Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz`)
- Monitors: [Dual 27' LG QHD Monitors](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27qp88d-b2)

  - Resolution: 2560 x 1440
  - Refresh Rate: 75Hz

The docking station is working with everything except the external displays. I'm running into two separate issues.

1. The monitor attached via HDMI to the hub is showing up in displays and is able to be enabled. When enabled my computer does function like the display is enabled but it remains blank.
2. The monitor attached via DP to the hub is recognized by Ubuntu but when trying to enable it I get a **"could not set configuration for crtc 64"**

[image]

Originally when attaching the hub with either monitor plugged into it the entire system would black screen and freeze until it was unplugged at which point it would give me a **"could not set configuration for crtc 64"**. After googling around I ended up updating my kernel from 5.3.0 to 5.19.17 which put me in the state I mentioned above (so I can now try to debug a bit). This did not fully install correctly so I do plan/hope on being able to revert back to my original kernel version once I figure this out.

OS Stats:

```
### lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

```
### uname -r

5.19.17-051917-generic
```

```
### xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     59.98*+  59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   2560x1440     59.95 +
   3840x2160     30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    29.97  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
DP-1-2 connected 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     74.97*+
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    29.97  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94
```

```
### lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0
```

```
### sudo X -version

X.Org X Server 1.20.8
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 5.4.0-135-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux stephanie 5.19.17-051917-generic #202210240939 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct 24 09:43:01 UTC 2022 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.17-051917-generic root=UUID=0f75530f-31a7-4e3e-b51a-a5767ee9a76b ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Build Date: 07 December 2022  02:15:34PM
xorg-server-hwe-18.04 2:1.20.8-2ubuntu2.2~18.04.9 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

Since the kernel upgrade `lshw` is throwing a `segmentation fault` when run. Looking into how to resolve this but I can't get any info out of that command currently.

As another note I am still running Unity7 and not gnome, I don't believe this makes a difference since they both use X for the display server but thought I'd mention it in case.

I'm pretty sure that my laptop should be able to support dual monitors through its thunderbolt (looking at the external display section in the linked specs) so I am hoping this can be resolved. Any help would be super useful, please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide that would help debug this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on a few posts, the installation from synaptics does the job:
https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu
Seems that thunderbolt isn't involved here.